# how to get block of xml code through perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

From morning i was scratching my head to resolve the below requirment. I know how to parse an xml but not able to find out the sollution to get the exact block along with tags.

**sample code:**

```
<employee name="sample1">
 <interest name="cricket">
<function action= "bowling">
   <rating> average </rating>
</function>
 </interest>
 <interest name="football">
<function action="defender">
   <rating> good </rating>
</function>
 </interest>
</employee>
```

I just want to extract the below content from above xml file and write it into another text file.

```
  <interest name="cricket">
     <function action= "bowling">
        <rating> average </rating>
     </function>
  </interest>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm really not sure exactly what you're asking here.  What specific problem are you having?

Comment: I just wanted to take the xml block <interest name="cricket"> </interest> into some text file from the above sample code

Comment: So what you want to do is parse an xml, then print only a subset of it, unchanged, to a separate file?

Comment: Sorry.. I mean how to extact that content from the xml file and write to text file

Comment: @LoneShepherd yes i want exactly what you said

Comment: So, I would use an xml parsing module like XML::Simple to parse the input file with XMLin().  From there you will get a reference data structure; you can pick pieces of that to then output with XMLout()

Comment: @LoneShepherd yes i tried but as i was new to this i wasn't able to suceed can you please give me sample stech of code so that i can go ahead thanks in adavance

Comment: Show us your work so we can give suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Using XML::Twig:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'interest[@name="cricket"]' => sub { $_->print } },
              )
         ->parsefile( 'interest.xml');
```

A little explanation: the twig_handler is called when an element satisfying the trigger condition, in this case `interest[@name="cricket"]`, is satisfied. At this point the associated sub is called. In the sub `$_` is set to be the current element, which is then print'ed. For more complex subs, 2 arguments are passed, the twig itself (the document) and the current element.

Voilà.

Also with XML::Twig comes a tool called `xml_grep`, which makes it easy to extract what you want:

```
xml_grep --nowrap 'interest[@name="cricket"]' interest.xml
```

the `--nowrap` option prevents the default behaviour which wraps the results in a containing element.

Comment: Hello Mirod thanlks alot for your help

Comment: Hello Mirod thanlks alot for your help
Will it be possilble to get the content under <interest name="cricket">
<function action= "bowling"> thats means join of element?

Comment: OK, you got me right as I was typing an answer, so here it is anyways: the action attribute would be `$_->first_child( 'function')->att( 'action')` and the rating would be `$_->findvalue( 'function/rating')` or `$_->first_child( 'function')->first_child( 'rating')->text`

Comment: Mirod, Is there any way to write
XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'interest[@name="cricket"]' => sub { $_->print } },
              )
         ->parsefile( 'interest.xml');

the output to write into text file instead of printing in console

Comment: as per the docs: use `print_to_file`,. Note that this will work only if you extract 1 single element, otherwise you can open a file and then pass the file handle to print: `open( my $fh, '>', 'my_file.xml') or die "cannot create file: $!";` then in the handler:`$_->print( $fh)`

Comment: Mirod can you please provide the like to related to document of XML:Twig module. I searched but i didn't found :(

Comment: on Unix: `perldoc XML::Twig` or `man XML::Twig`, also, look at http://xmltwig.org/xmltwig/